# Storing social media profile details in a graph based db

Tags: java, mongodb, graph, neo4j, database

I'm building an application where I collect the user profiles from various social media and store them as part of my application. Initially I was thinking of using a NoSQL like mongoDB for storing these details. But I also need to store information who is connected to whom on which social medium. To achieve this, a graph based datastore seems to be the apt one.

But the structure of data that I get from different social media is not consistent. Hence I was thinking of storing just the email ids as part of graph db (neo4j) and all profile data as part of mongoDB. Any other suggestions or would this hamper performance later on?

Comment: Everything here would largely depend on your use case and usage patterns. Schema-less stores pretty much excel at storing data from different sources, and within reason then even possibly in the same "collection" ( in the MongoDB sense ). Unless you have a clear usage pattern that defines why you want to introduce different moving parts then you may be over-complicating at an early stage. If you really want advise on your application architecture, then I would advise breaking that up into a series of less broad questions.

Comment: The main reason why I wanted to use neo4j was to ensure that I store the "connection" relationship. The main use case as of now is to get some profile information given an email id. But eventually I would want to recommend user profiles based on a user's skill set / interests etc. which is when I would need to know how people are connected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use email address as the primary key, what if you find that the same user has used 2 different email address ? best to always have a synthetic key to which you can map multiple email addresses.

Its been more than 2 years since I experimented with Neo4j, I came away feeling that it was not worth the effort, we spent way more time trying to get the GC right on Neo4j than solving our business problems. You cannot partition your data (i.e shard) only way to scale is to have one master and many read slaves.

Comment: Then how would you suggest to store the connections / friends relation in DB? I thought a graph database was the way to go.

Comment: There are GraphDB's other than Neo4j and you could always store in a relation model if you can't find one.